# Assigning Date+TIme Picker Variables to a DateTime (Joda) or Date Variable

Tags: java, android, datepicker, jodatime

I have been trying out many solutions for this problem for a while now and have had no luck.

I have 2 pickers, one a date picker and one a time picker. When the user selects their date and time the selections are stored in these variables:

- int dayNow
- monthNow
- yearNow
- hourNow
- minuteNow

What I am trying to achieve is that I can assign these variables into a DateTime variable. for example:

> DateTime timeselectedbyuser = dayNow + monthNow + yearNow + hourNow+ minuteNow;

The reason why I need it to be of type DateTime is that I am working with JodaTime and am doing a calculation that gets the difference in time in minutes between the current time and the time the user has selected through my date pickers.

Here is some method that I have tried that is unsuccessful:

```
//START DATE SELECTED BY USER
            timeselectedbyuser = DateTime.parse(String.valueOf(dayNow + monthNow + yearNow + hourNow + minuteNow));

            //CURRENT DATE
            currentdatetime = new DateTime();
            DateTimeFormatter form = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd MMM yyyy" + " h:mm a ");


            long millis1 = timeselectedbyuser.getMillis();
            long milis2 = currentdatetime.getMillis();
            long diff = milis2 - millis1;

            long diffinMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000);



            diffinmins.setText((int) diffinMinutes);
```

Could anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is that you can't simply add `int` variables and parse them as a `String` to get the `DateTime`. You either have to use a format or use one of `org.joda.time.DateTime` constructors provided by jodatime [Doc](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime-int-int-int-int-int-):

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(yearNow, monthNow, dayNow, hourNow, minuteNow);
```

or using `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:MM:dd:HH:mm");
Date date = null;
try {
    date = simpleDateFormat.parse(yearNow + ":" + monthNow + ":" + dayNow + ":" + hourNow + ":" + minuteNow);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
```

Check the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to find the proper format string for your date format. For example you'd have to use `HH` if you are using a 24 hour clock or `KK:a` if you use a 12 hour clock.

Hope this helped